# How can I catch the OnClosing Event from a Ribbon Window?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

In my application I used to use the wpf windows where are extendd from System.WIndows.Window.

I am thinking of migrate them to using Ribbon Windows which are extended From ToolWindow.

Unfortunately I can't use the OnClosing event with Ribbon windows.

How can I trigger when a window is closed?

I need something like the following

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) {
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi! To start: Are you using the latest version? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
on XAML add Closing

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow x:Class="RibbonWindowSample.RibbonWindowWord"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ribbon="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RibbonWindowSample"
    Title="RibbonWindowWord" Height="600" Width="1000"

    Closing="RibbonWindow_Closing"
>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
</ribbon:RibbonWindow>
```

on Code add

```
private void RibbonWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Confirm?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't worked. The closing event needs a delegate of RoutedEventArgs. Worth trying